# Java: In socket programming if client write different type of Objects how server differentiate these object instances?

Tags: java, sockets

Well, my question is simple In socket programming if client write different type of Objects how server differentiate these object instances?

Updated:

Take for example if the client sends a string object how the server is suppose to know that it should cast the receiving bytes into a string object?

Comment: The answer depends completely on which protocol you are using to send objects across the socket. Provide more information (e.g., show us the code) and maybe we can answer your question. As it stands now, this question is too broad to provide a proper answer.

Comment: Send a header that describes what it is you are planning to send. The problem of deciding how to send data and what data to send is called a **protocol**. This is one of the main reasons people use HTTP or STOMP rather than implementing their own.

Comment: Take for example if the client sends a string object how the server is suppose to know that it should cast the receiving bytes into a string object?

Comment: I am using tcp protocol

Comment: You can take a look at this one that was asked once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258815/server-receive-any-kind-of-object-type-in-a-java-networking-application/27259297#27259297

Comment: The TCP protocol sends _bytes_. That you have succeeded in doing. How you need another layer _above_ TCP.

Comment: TCP works on a lower level of the protocol stack; it makes sure your bytes get delivered (completely and in the right sequence) but doesn't care at all what those bytes mean. For that reason, there are other protocols like HTTP on top of TCP; they provide details e.g. about the kind of data that is transfered. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Comment: I recently did a tutorial on socket programming, http://www.coding.ractoc.com/socket-programming-part-1/ In the last part, there's some hint on setting up your own protocol. What areas you need to take into consideration as well as some proposed solutions.

Comment: Guys, your patience deeply impresses me. @essaji: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a Socket you are using a TCP connection, so there's not any abstraction of the Application layer in this communication.

Remember TCP/IP stack:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+    APPLICATION LAYER     +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ TRASPORT (TCP/UDP) LAYER +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The Socket only knows about TCP headers, so it doesn't know anything about the real type of the data, it only knows about TCP packets.

As Boris told you, the application layer is in charge of this know-how. You can use many options:

- Send a header (an application header) that can tell every consumer how to deal with this data
- Send a representation of the object. Use a technology-aware format: XML, JSON, YAML, etc...

Comment: Well, explained. thanks! :)